# ValueError when trying to reconfigure Siamese network trained on triplets to operate on pairs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

### My problem

I am trying to implement a Siamese network in Keras that is trained on triplets—`[anchor_input, similar_input, different_input]`—and executes on pairs—`[input_a, input_b]`—telling me whether they are similar or different. I am able to train fine on triplets, and have even trained and tested on pairs, but when I train on triplets and try to *create* my pair-wise network, I get the following error:

> ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape (() vs (?, ?))

## Current network overview

My triplet network is defined using the following code, which I have pared down to something pretty minimal for this example:

```
def siamese_triplet(in_shape, feature_dim):
    input_a = Input(shape=in_shape)  # input is a series, n_samples by n_features
    input_b = Input(shape=in_shape)
    input_c = Input(shape=in_shape)
    base_network = create_model()  # makes my Siamese kernel network
    processed_a = base_network(input_a)  # base_network outputs a vector, say 50 elements long
    processed_b = base_network(input_b)
    processed_c = base_network(input_c)
    l1_distance = lambda x: K.abs(x[0] - x[1])  # vector, 50 elements long
    p_distance = Lambda(l1_distance,
                        output_shape=lambda x: x[0])([processed_a, processed_b])
    n_distance = Lambda(l1_distance,
                        output_shape=lambda x: x[0])([processed_a, processed_c])
    triplet_loss = Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(K.maximum(0, x[0] - x[1] + 1)),
                          output_shape=(1,))([p_distance, n_distance])  # scalar
    model = Model([input_a, input_b, input_c], triplet_loss)
    optimizer = SGD()
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss=lambda x, y: y)  # passes triplet loss through
```

I train the network and get a fitted `model` object out. I then try to re-create the network with a structure built around input pairs, passing it the `base_network` layer extracted from my `model`, which ends up being `model.layers[3]`:

```
# triplet_net = siamese_triplet(...)
# model = triplet_net.fit(...)
pair_net = siamese_pair(input_shape, model.layers[3])
```

with `siamese_pair` defined as:

```
def siamese_pair(in_shape, base_network):
    input_a = Input(shape=in_shape)
    input_b = Input(shape=in_shape)
    processed_a = base_network(input_a)  # vector, 50 elements
    processed_b = base_network(input_b)
    distance = Lambda(lambda x: K.abs(x[0] - x[1]),
                      output_shape=lambda x: x[0])([processed_a, processed_b])  # vector, 50 elements
    prediction = Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x),
                        output_shape=(1,))(distance)  # scalar
    model = Model([input_a, input_b], prediction)
    optimizer = SGD()
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss='binary_crossentropy')  # for evaluation purposes
```

The `model.compile(...)` line throws the error.

Note that the triplet loss should push distances close to zero for objects that are the same (class `0`), and push them towards 1 for objects that are different (class `1`), so setting `prediction = K.mean(distance)` should be pretty close to one of these class labels, I would think.

My transition from triplet-loss training to pair-wise evaluation seems kind of janky to me, and I would love to figure out the *best* way to do it, so I am open to suggestions to improve the design. In the mean time, I would be happy just getting past this error so I can at least run and evaluate my performance classifying input pairs as similar or different.

### My questions

1. Why am I getting the error above? It seems like it is expecting no `y_true` *at all* for the loss function, which is strange to me.
2. How do I *fix* the error above?
3. Is there a better way to pass my trained `base_layer` into a different Siamese network structure?
4. Is there a better way to get pair-wise predictions out of my trained `base_layer` in a different network structure?

Answers to just the first two would be great, but if somebody has suggestions on the last two as well, I am all ears.

Comment: Apologizes for my ignorance, but what is the output shape of `base_network=create_model()`?

Comment: Good question! The `base_network` takes as input a single sample (time series with several features, in my case), and outputs a single vector, say 50 elements long.

Comment: I added some comments to the code to give approximate dimensions of results throughout. The actual number isn't important, so I just went with 50 elements for the output of `base_network`.